# Wget cant download file but browser can

Tags: error-handling, scripting, wget

I have an url like

```
http:\/\/23.246.50.145\/?o=AQFsBQ9SB1l-S4Ch0gw3lM0zSs4ReWo3_PsOqoF35YR0eHrAqxQ7GIRonzVp_nrrJ4m9cKer-YAmV-rgYJXHJ1NE9JjLqf78Jp7l9Y-z2njJVV2CpXDAPNoh91iqrDA2vRuNdlvYbbSJ4Sj5Mp-xiegEeAKXnQ&v=3&e=1494051078&t=XUSkPrEHFE2Tas3F9KxR7CPINPI
```

If i type this url in a browser it starts downloading a file that will named just download Which is actually a music file so i just rename it to .mp4

If I try to use wget it wont work

```
wget "http:\/\/23.246.50.145\/?o=AQFsBQ9SB1l- S4Ch0gw3lM0zSs4ReWo3_PsOqoF35YR0eHrAqxQ7GIRonzVp_nrrJ4m9cKer-YAmV-rgYJXHJ1NE9JjLqf78Jp7l9Y-z2njJVV2CpXDAPNoh91iqrDA2vRuNdlvYbbSJ4Sj5Mp-xiegEeAKXnQ&v=3&e=1494051078&t=XUSkPrEHFE2Tas3F9KxR7CPINPI"
```

Will get this error

```
--2017-05-04 09:10:51--    http://23.246.50.145/?o=AQFsBQ9SB1l-S4Ch0gw3lM0zSs4ReWo3_PsOqoF35YR0eHrAqxQ7GIRonzVp_nrrJ4m9cKer-YAmV-rgYJXHJ1NE9JjLqf78Jp7l9Y-z2njJVV2CpXDAPNoh91iqrDA2vRuNdlvYbbSJ4Sj5Mp-xiegEeAKXnQ&v=3&e=1494051078&t=XUSkPrEHFE2Tas3F9KxR7CPINPI
Connecting to 23.246.50.145:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 420
2017-05-04 09:10:51 ERROR 420: (no description).
```

Why is this error?

Answer (score 0):

I got forbidden. You must use ' instead of "

like

```
wget -d 'http://23.246.50.145/?o=AQFsBQ9SB1l-S4Ch0gw3lM0zSs4ReWo3_PsOqoF35YR0eHrAqxQ7GIRonzVp_nrrJ4m9cKer-YAmV-rgYJXHJ1NE9JjLqf78Jp7l9Y-z2njJVV2CpXDAPNoh91iqrDA2vRuNdlvYbbSJ4Sj5Mp-xiegEeAKXnQ&v=3&e=1494051078&t=XUSkPrEHFE2Tas3F9KxR7CPINPI'
```